# How to use knockout foreach elements and post them?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, foreach

I want to use HTTP post pattern to submit data, but my form data is konckout foreach result. like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="testFlag" value="flag"/>
    <div data-bind="foreach: users">
     <input type="hidden" data-bind="name:'UserID['+$index+']',value:user.Guid"/>
     <input type="hidden" data-bind="name:'UserName['+$index+']',value:user.name"/>
     ...
     </div>
```

I need submit List. UserController cannot get request values, but testFlag has value. Do you have any suggestion or detail material?

Thanks all guys replies!

Comment: Have you actually checked the final markup? I think the correct binding should be something like: `...data-bind="attr:{'name':'UserName['+$index+']'},...`.

Comment: Can you please post of your `UserController` action signature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fix the following things in your bindings:

- There is no built in `name` binding exits, you need to use the [`attr` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html) to set the `name` attribute
- `$index` is an observable so you need to write `$index()` to get its value in an expression.
- APS.NET MVC needs the following naming conventions when binding to lists: `yourListPropertyName[index].propertyName` see also in [Model binding to a list](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/)

Putting it all together the correct syntax is (assuming that in your controller parameter the List is stored in property named `Users`) :

```
 <input type="hidden" data-bind="attr: { name: 'Users['+$index()+'].UserID' }, value:user.Guid"/>
 <input type="hidden" data-bind="attr: { name: 'Users['+$index()+'].UserName'}, value:user.name"/>
```

Comment: Hi Nemesv, A big thanks for you. You are very professional. :)